# Can't click point from KML if inside Polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi all This is the scenario:

1. Have a KML layer with points of data, with description, if you click on marker it will popup description. KML layer added via:
   *geoxml= new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://MYRURL',{preserveViewport:true});

   geoxml.setMap(map);*
2. Have a polygon made with coords array directly on map with
   *poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
     paths: polyCoords,
     strokeColor: "#0000FF",
     strokeOpacity: 1,
     strokeWeight: 2,
     fillColor: "#FF0000",
     fillOpacity: 0.2
   });*

Problem: I can click (Green Arrow on image) and see data of description for points outside polygon but cannot (red arrows on image) of the ones geo-inside the polygon. I will like to see infowindows of those too, Poly AFAIK has no click listener.

I have tested setMap the KMLLayer before and after setMap of poly..

See attached image.
[image: MAP with KML Layer and poly]

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your kmllayer is getting the click event rather than the map which has the markers on it.
Add the "clickable: false" option.

Like so:

```
new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://MYRURL',{preserveViewport:true, clickable: false});
```

Works in google maps api v3.